# Prevent a UIPopover from being presented as UIPageSheet on iPhone 6 plus in landscape

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus, uitraitcollection

I'm trying to show a `popOver` with a `UISlider` inside, to allow an user to control the `textSize` of a `WKWebView`.

Here is how I did it:

```
MYCustomViewController *popoverContent = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MYCustomViewController"];
    popoverContent.delegate = self;
    popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController;
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(220, 40);
    popover.delegate = self;
    popover.barButtonItem = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    [self presentViewController:popoverContent animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the custom `ViewController` I just added a delegate to get the value of the `UISlider`

I also implemented the method:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
  return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Everything works just fine on every device except the iPhone 6 Plus in Landscape (i.e. compact height), which displays the `popover` as `UIPageSheet`

Note: I present the popover from a `UIbarButtonItem`, in the `detailViewController` of a `UISplitViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by implementing the new `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:` method of `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate:` as suggested by @Joshua

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    // This method is called in iOS 8.3 or later regardless of trait collection, in which case use the original presentation style (UIModalPresentationNone signals no adaptation)
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

`UIModalPresentationNone` tells the presentation controller to use the original presentation style which in your case will display a `popover`.